# how to que the exceeded limit emails in nextday in sendgrid free account

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid free account for sending emails in my php website.
It provides 400 mails per day

This is the code

```
// using SendGrid's PHP Library - https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($api_user, $api_key);
$email    = new SendGrid\Email();

$email->addTo("test@sendgrid.com")
      ->setFrom("you@youremail.com")
      ->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun")
      ->setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");

$sendgrid->send($email);
```

This code is working fine. If the mails exceed 400 then how to send remaining mails in nextday in free accout. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Once you've hit your limit, you'll need to save these emails into a database or some kind of storage. Then, with cron or an automated script, go through the queue and send them on their way. If you are reaching on an average of more than 400 a day, then queuing them for the next day isn't really feasible. Eventually, you'll just need to find a free service that offers more emails per day, or just go with them and pay for their services.

Comment: Could you provide more information on where these emails are coming from or who they go to. As the above comment suggests if you're hitting 400 per day on a regular basis you might want to upgrade, otherwise you are engineering a solution that doesn't necessarily need to be there.

Comment: ok thank you. how get count of how many emails sent in a day from snedgrid in free account.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've hit your limit, you'll need to save these emails into a database or some kind of storage. Then, with cron or an automated script, go through the queue and send them on their way. If you are reaching on an average of more than 400 a day, then queuing them for the next day isn't really feasible. Eventually, you'll just need to find a free service that offers more emails per day, or just go with them and pay for their services.